# How to avoid new paragraph after code block in Org-mode?

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

When Org-mode exports to LaTeX it produces a new paragraph after code blocks. How can I avoid this?

Consider the following example:

```
#+TITLE: Example

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(setq foo "bar")
#+END_SRC
A paragraph contains some text and this text only serves as example text.
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(setq bar "foo")
#+END_SRC
```

It exports to the following LaTeX

```latex
\begin{verbatim}
(setq foo "bar")
\end{verbatim}



A paragraph contains some text and this text only serves as example text.

\begin{verbatim}
(setq bar "foo")
\end{verbatim}
```

which outputs as

[image: The output I get]

Note that the text after the first code block is set as a new paragraph. I do not want it to be set as a new paragraph. I want it to be set as

[image: The output I want]

which is the output of:

```latex
\begin{verbatim}
(setq foo "bar")
\end{verbatim}
A paragraph contains some text and this text only serves as example text.
\begin{verbatim}
(setq bar "foo")
\end{verbatim}
```

I am running Org-mode 7.6 in Emacs 23.3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not seem to be an issue in `Org 7.8.03`.  Testing your exact code block provides the following output

Org

```
#+TITLE: Example

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(setq foo "bar")
#+END_SRC
A paragraph contains some text and this text only serves as example text.
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(setq bar "foo")
#+END_SRC
```

LaTeX

```latex
\begin{verbatim}
(setq foo "bar")
\end{verbatim}
A paragraph contains some text and this text only serves as example text.

\begin{verbatim}
(setq bar "foo")
\end{verbatim}
```

Output

[image: Output result]

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this is not the solution you want, but anyways, you can set indentation manually with

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(setq foo "bar")
#+END_SRC
#+LATEX:\noindent
A paragraph contains some text and this text only serves as example text.
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(setq bar "foo")
#+END_SRC
```